# Is $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)$ of finite length?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $A$ be a regular local ring, and let $M$ and $N$ be two finitely generated $A$-modules such that $M\otimes N$ is of finite length, and let $i$ be the largest integer such that $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)\neq 0$. Can we prove that $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)$ is of finite length?

This appears on page 111 of *Local Algebra* by Serre, line 8. Perhaps one does not need the ring to be regular to prove the above statement.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to show that the support of $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)$ consists only of maximal ideals. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal such that $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)_{\mathfrak p}\neq 0$, equivalently $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p})\neq 0$. In particular we have $M_{\mathfrak p}\neq 0$ and $N_{\mathfrak p}\neq 0$. Since $A$ is local we get $M_{\mathfrak p}\otimes_{R_{\mathfrak p}}N_{\mathfrak p}\neq 0$, equivalently $(M\otimes N)_{\mathfrak p}\neq 0$. Since $M\otimes N$ has finite length it follows that $\mathfrak p$ is maximal.

**Remark.** As one can see there is no need to assume that $A$ is regular.

Comment: This is a great answer, and infact very easy. I should have thought more, but since last 2 days i have been struggling to finish that theorem and i finally did, and the above observation was the only thing missing. Thank you very much. I dont know how to upvote this answer, or else i would immediately do so.

Comment: By the way this is messi, you had replied to a few questions from me before, unfortunately i lost that id on here.